# using coroutines for debouncing

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, debouncing

Having a function `updateData(id:String, data: Any?)`, which will do some data update against the `id`.
Would like to only update with the last data, if this call is for same `id` too soon one after the other the previous one should be dropped.

```
    private var _lastId = ""
    private var _lastCallJob: Job? = null
    private fun debouncingUpdateData(id: String, data: Any?) {

        if (_lastId == id) {
            _lastCallJob?.cancel()
            _lastCallJob = launch {
                delay(20)
                updateData(id, data)
            }
        } else {
            _lastId = id
            _lastCallJob = launch {
                delay(20)
                updateData(id, data)
            }
        }
    }
```

this implementation will cancel the previously launched `_lastCallJob` (unfinished, most likely still in the 20 milsec waiting), only if the id is the same.

But it does not work well for the case like
id = "1",  id="2", id="3"

so when calling like:

```
debouncingUpdateData("1", data)
debouncingUpdateData("2", data)
debouncingUpdateData("1", data)
```

the 3rd call for id==="1" may still goes out (even if the 1st one is still in the 20 milsec delay range), since the the `_lastId` has been changed to "2".

any better way to do the debouncing with coroutines?

Comment: have you considered using Flow and its built-in `debounce` method? https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/debounce.html

Comment: @fraggjkee, havent, thought just use whatever version of kotlin we are using. thx! Admit that not knowing how to use Flow yet, how would it help for this multiple "id" calling same function case?

Comment: as a quick idea, you could create a coroutine Channel and post ID updates to it. Then you can convert this channel to Flow with the existing `asFlow` function. The last step would be to add the `debounce` method to this stream and just observe its emissions and react as required (load data, etc.). Pretty similar to what I'd do with Rx - `Subject` + `debounce` but using Coroutines & Flow.

Comment: sounds like there will be more code (will take a look), maybe will just adding a map (id to job) with the code I have.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if there is some simpler library function, but seems this does the debouncing for multiple `id` case

```
    private val idToJobMap = HashMap<String, Job>()
    private fun debouncingUpdateData(id: String, data: Any?) {

        idToJobMap[id]?.let { job ->
            job.cancel()
        }
        idToJobMap[id] = launch {
            delay(20)
            idToJobMap.remove(id)
            updateData(data)
        }
    }
```